# Get current location using GWT-Maps-V3-Api

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

can somebody please help mt to get current location of user using the GWT-Maps-V3-Api and her eis the link to it.

https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/blob/master/README.md.

In the google gwt map there is a class called geoLocation which gives you the current coordinates of the user. But in GWT-Maps-V3-Api i could not find anything or am i missing something.Please help me to get started.

Comment: _"In the google gwt map there is a class called geoLocation"_ What "google gwt map"?

Comment: You're saying that the library doesn't provide a function you found somewhere else. Where did you find it?

Comment: i think you got me wrong. I mentioned in the google map there is a class geoLocation which can be used to implement the current location but in branflake version I dont see this class. so my question is how can i get the current location of the machine using branflake's version of gwt map v3 api. i will appreciate your help

Comment: Yeah, but "in google map" isn't helpful. Do you mean the javascript library?

Comment: somebody please help me get started

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful : http://blog.vercer.com/2012/12/google-maps-v3-with-gwt-example.html
However, I don't know how to handle cases when GeoLocation.getIfSupported() returns null!